# What is the default ability for any unspecified users in the ability file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan

In my `ability.rb` file I defined the role checks for some users but not all users like following:

```
if user.role? :superadmin
  can :manage, :all
elsif user.role? :admin
  can :manage, :all
end
```

But the application has a total of 6 users. Will there be any default abilities set for the users that I have not mentioned explicitly here? If yes, what is their default ability?

Answer (score 0):

No. When you haven't defined any abilities for your users, your users will have no abilities. This means that they can't access anything (except for parts of your page where you might skip authorization).

Answer (score 0):

If you have not defined the roles of other users they will not be able to access anything on your application. In your case only the users with `superadmin` and `admin` roles can access your application. Others are not able to access your application's functionalities.